# Twitter style load more on asp.net repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hi does any one have any good examples of twitter style load more items, how would i go about achieving this in an asp.net repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to get it with asp.net repeater but check out [infinitScroll](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/infiniScroll) plugin.